# Where can I get the export format for exchanges?

Tags: exchanges, coinbase.com, bitfinex

I am trying to get the format that a large number of exchanges use to export their data.

So when a user clicks export my trades, there is usually a csv file which has a specific format to it.

I would like to get a large number of these formats, as they do vary depending on the exchange. Without signing up for each exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion is to contact each exchange (technical support/development/API support?) directly (without signing up) to request a template. Hopefully, they will be happy to be of assistance once you explain why you need them.